# Arfter reinstalling arch linux wifi isn't recognised on any os

Tags: arch-linux, wifi, manjaro, firmware

Arfter I  reinstalled Arch linux I was getting a problem where it didn't recognize the wifi chip in my computer, fed up with having to actually deal with stuff like this I wiped the drive and installed windows untill I could get Linux up and running but windows didn't recognize the wifi driver's either until i completed the setup Process. Manjaro doesn't recognize that I have wifi on my laptop either. I assume it's something to do with driver's but don't know how to fix it. Is there a fix to this?

Comment: it's not quite clear - can Windows after all wifi or not? From the Q title I understand that no, from the Q content - that at the end wifi works.

Comment: including the brand/model of laptop in your question would help ... also, check the output of `dmesg` after booting, sometimes linux recognises the device, but needs extra drivers/firmware installed - often this is actually described in the dmesg error!

Comment: So when I installed windows it didn't recognize that I had wifi on my computer until I fully installed it

Comment: The laptop is a thinkpad E14 what's funny about it though is when I use the arch installation media it detects that I have wifi but the when doing the Manjaro or windows installation doesn't recognize it at all